# What is the exact meaning of "I dig it"?

Tags: expressions, slang

I have received feedback for a song I composed and some peers used the expression "I dig it". I know it should be interpreted as positive but, to what extent?

Answer (score 6):

From [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dig) dictionary:

> **dig**
>
> 3. *informal with object*
>
>    > Like, appreciate, or understand.
>    >     *‘I really dig heavy rock’*

I think it's safe to say that their comment is high praise indeed.

Answer (score 3):

"Dig" is slang and suggests first that the music/song is liked (liked a lot), and second that it is understood.

Answer (score 2):

Used in this sense the verb ***dig*** means to admire or appreciate, and though it is now rather dated it was part of the pop music *lingua franca* of the 1950s and 60s.

OED sense 6c has examples from 1935 to 1969 - it is said to be of US origin.

> 6c. slang (orig. U.S.).  (a) To understand, appreciate, like, admire; 
>   (b) to look at or listen to; to experience. Cf. sense  1c.
>
> 1935   Hot News Sept. 20/2   If you listen enough, and dig him enough,
>   you will realise that that..riff is the high-spot of the record.
>
> 1941   Life 15 Dec. 89   Dig me?
>
> 1943   M. Shulman Barefoot Boy 90   Awful fine slush pump, I mean
>   awful fine. You ought to dig that.
>
> 1944   C. Calloway Hepsters Dict.   Dig v.—(1) Meet. (2) Look, see.
>   (3) Comprehend, understand.
>
> 1944   M. Zolotow Never whistle in Dressing Room iii. 52   When they
>   see a pretty girl they shout, ‘Dig the chick.’
>
> 1947   R. de Toledano Frontiers of Jazz p. x,   I recognize it when I
>   see it, the same as I dig good Jazz when I hear it.
>
> 1949   L. Feather Inside Be-bop iii. 28   Dizzy didn't dig the band's
>   kind of music and the band didn't dig Dizzy.
>
> 1958   Punch 8 Jan. 92/1   The lines of communication get tangled. In
>   other words the people don't quite ‘dig’ you.
>
> 1958   Listener 29 May 912/1   He wants to ‘dig’ the whole of life,
>   and is convinced that experience comes only to the irresponsible.
>
> 1958   Punch 25 June 853/3   Does the beat generation really dig such
>   crazy old-world catch-phrases?
>
> 1959   C. MacInnes Absolute Beginners 60   If you like the other
>   number, I mean like the looks of them, really dig them sexually.
>
> 1959   C. MacInnes Absolute Beginners 62   Everything you learned, you
>   hadn't learned until you'd really dug it: i.e., made it part of your
>   own experience.
>
> 1960   N. Mitford Don't tell Alfred xviii. 192   Of course he's a
>   man's man, you might not dig him like we do.
>
> 1969   New Yorker 29 Nov. 48/1,   I just don't dig any of these guys.
>   I don't understand their scenes.

Note that the OED does refer to sense 1c, suggesting that there may be a connection. It has origins from as early as 1789

> 1c. fig. with allusion to the general sense; also spec. to study hard
>   and closely at a subject (U.S.). Hence, to understand (cf. sense  6c
>   (slang (orig. U.S.)).
>
> 1789   Trifler No. 43. 549   Youths who never digged for the rich ore
>   of knowledge thro' the pages of the Rambler.
>
> 1801   R. Southey Thalaba I. iv. 220   'Tis a spring of living waters,
>   Whose inexhaustible bounties all might drink But few dig deep enough.
>
> 1827   Harvard Reg. (1828) Dec. 303   Here the sunken eye and sallow
>   countenance bespoke the man who dug sixteen hours‘ per diem’.
>
> 1869   L. M. Alcott Little Women II. xii. 177   Laurie ‘dug’ to some
>   purpose that year.
>
> 1936   N.Y. World Telegram 6 Oct. 16/1   ‘You dig?’ is a short cut for
>   ‘You understand?’
>
> 1952   B. Ulanov Hist. Jazz in Amer. xxiv. 344   The man who really
>   ‘digs’ can more often than not describe the next development in jazz
>   before the musicians have reached it.
>
> 1957   C. MacInnes City of Spades i. xi. 89   Twist now—you dig?

Answer (score 1):

This particular use of 'dig' can mean either to *like* or *understand* something. It could also mean a combination of the two, as a general verb of *approval* for something.

The term was particularly popular during the 1960s-1970s and is today considered slightly old-fashioned. It seems to be mainly used today in connection with music, perhaps as a deliberate homage to the music and associated culture of that era.

Answer (score 0):

That they 'dig' your song is a great compliment - shows that they can relate to it and also loved it! It's a cool way of praising!

Answer (score -1):

It originates with the Irish language Tuigim meaning "I understand". https://inirish.bitesize.irish/339

Comment: Welcome to [ell.se]! That is not supported by the linked website, could you [edit] to provide more evidence please?

Comment: No. It's true I'm telling them. That's as much effort as I put in for free.